# Capture `UIImageView` properties with lldb and python

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, uiimageview, lldb

I am trying to use LLDB and python to debug my view hierarchy. When I set a breakpoint in XCode and explore the frame value like:

```
expr @import UIKit
po self.imageView.frame
```

LLDB is able to execute the command as shown:

[image]

When I try to replicate the same command using python scripting like so:

```
import lldb

lldb.debugger.HandleCommand('expr @import UIKit')
expression = 'self.imageView.frame'
frame = lldb.debugger.GetSelectedTarget().GetProcess().GetSelectedThread().GetSelectedFrame()
expr_options = lldb.SBExpressionOptions()
language = frame.GetCompileUnit().GetLanguage()
expr_options.SetLanguage(language)
value = frame.EvaluateExpression(expression, expr_options)
```

The value of the expression `value.GetValue()` is `None`.

How do I get the value of `self.imageView.frame` using lldb python scripting so I can do further computations on that value in Python?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`frame` is an aggregate type (a structure or class object) and aggregate types don't have values since they aren't any particular unitary thing...

They have Summaries - a pretty printed text rendition of the contents of an aggregate type - which you can access with `SBValue::GetSummary`.  Note, these summaries are provided by lldb's Data Formatter mechanism, which same mechanism is also used in normal variable printing, and for example provides what you are seeing in the po result..  So if you want to just emulate the kind of printing you would get from the command line, the Summary is what you want.

SBValues representing aggregate types also have members - that's the "real" contents of the value.  In SBValue parlance these are called children, and you can access them via the SBValue API's (e.g. `SBValue::GetNumChildren` & `SBValue::GetChildAtIndex`.)

Comment: I've tried you suggestion, and `value.num_children` is 0 and `value.GetSummary` is null. Am I missing something?

Comment: That sounds like you didn't get a valid object back from your expression.  When you get a value you should check the error (SBValue::GetError returns this.)  If Success() on the value returns true you are okay.  If not there's a message in the error which may tell you what went wrong.